# Ruby on Rails : Error trying to generate a model : Name already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to generate a model using the command

rails generate model Movie title:text year:integer rating:integer description:text

But I get the error :

```
 invoke  active_record The name 'Movie' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

I really want to keep the name Movie. I have also tried the below to delete the table - but the table does not exists in the database

```
sqlite> drop table Movie;
Error: no such table: Movie
```

I am not sure how to fix this error or what is causing it. Any help with this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you type Movie into rails console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can revert by running `rails destroy model Movie`. This will remove model, migration, tests, and fixtures that have been previously generated.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more or nominated as the accepted answer.
Found this when I made a similar error. either way, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The table name according to rails convention should be `movies`. Try with:

```
sqlite> drop table movies;
```

And make sure you don't have the model class (under `models/movie.rb`).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I destroyed the model and created a new one.

Answer (score 1):

**CASE I:: Cache issue**

I got below error::

**`The name 'Activityflow' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`**

While running **rails g** if you see below messages in initial lines. It could be cache issue:

```
warning: previous definition of CALLBACK_CAMPAIGN_NAME was here
Running via Spring preloader in process 98806
      invoke  active_record
```

Solution is kill spring and it will freeup cache.

Find process id of spring

```
$ ps -ef | grep spring
501 82388 82384   0  2:21PM ??        66:34.87 spring app    | insurance | started 16 hours ago | development mode      
501 82384     1   0  2:21PM ttys005    0:00.84 spring server | insurance | started 16 hours ago
```

Kill process Eg: 82384 in above case

```
$ kill -9 82384
```

Then when you run **rails g** command again; Spring will run/start with fresh contents and model creation succeed.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 99237
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20200518021818_create_activityflows.rb
  create    app/models/activityflow.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/activityflow_spec.rb
```

**CASE II:: Module Issue**

I got below error::

**`The name 'Workflow' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`**

The issue was I was using gem **gem 'workflow', '~> 2.0.2'** which creates modules names Workflow and does not allow to generate model named Workflow.

> So, be **careful when you use any gem** and is **module name in any gem gets
>   matched with model name.**

```
Simple way to check if module name exist is::
$ bin/rails c
[4] pry(main)> Workflow
=> Workflow
[5] pry(main)> Workflow.class
=> Module
```

Hope this helps to anyone who facing similar issues.